# is cloning quotes possible?

Tags: quote, cpq, clone, quote-template

Is it possible to clone quotes?

From my research, the information online seems to be conflicting:

1. It appears that this is not natively available with Salesforce, as this functionality has been requested in the IdeasExchange:
   https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdeM4UAJ/need-ability-to-clone-a-quote
2. Although, if you see the link below, we have the possibility to clone quotes to a new opportunity with the related button:
   https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000314869&type=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of quotes that Salesforce offers, the [Quote](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_quote.htm) object, and the [CPQ Quote](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cpq_quote_fields.htm&type=5) object. The former is the original Quote object that you get out of the box when you create a new org, the latter is an app that is installed into the org to extend Salesforce functionality. Of the two links, the first one refers to the standard Quote object, and the latter speaks about custom functionality built in to the CPQ Quote package. When checking documentation and other resources, make sure you pay attention as to which quote object is being talked about, as they are two entirely different implementations of the same thing. Also, in the general sense, for the question "is it possible to clone quotes," the answer is definitely "yes," if you allow for the possibility of using a Flow, Apex, JavaScript, etc; the nice part about Salesforce is that you can often extend the functionality however you like if you're willing to invest the time to customize or code the functionality.